# Don't shrink absolute positioned element with a max-width

Tags: css

I have a relatively positioned element containing an absolute positioned element. The inner element has these styles:

```
position: absolute;
max-width: 100px;
```

and I'm adding a `left` property via Javascript. The width of the inner element should be decided by the content, but it cannot be more than 200px.

If I now give the inner element a left position that would cause it to overflow the parent element, it shrinks. I want it to keep the width that it would have without the left position.

You can see an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/g079a5dL/

In that example I want the blue box to be 100px, and have it overflow the parent by 50px. Is this somehow possible with css? I know I can work around the issue by using a `right` property instead of `left`, but I want to try to avoid that for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a negative `margin-right`

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100px;
  left: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  margin-right:-100px; /* at least equal to max-width to cover all the cases*/
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
asda asd asd asd asdasd
</div>
</div>
```